# How to update Seekbar for Playing Video

Tags: android, seekbar

I am using IVideon Player and I have an URL which I want to play. Things are okay but I am unable to handle Seekbar status. I am getting 0 when I want to get time how much my video has been played. Please help me out. What I did is here

```
class SeekBarProgress implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        int totalDuration = event_list.get(counter).getDuration();

        for (int i = 0; i <= totalDuration; i++) {
            if (isPlaying) {
                final int value = i;
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                mTimeUpdateHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        strttime.setText(Utils.getDuration(Utils.getLong((double) value))); // the TextView Reference
                        mBufferBar.setProgress(value);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: your way of counting playback looks very weird. What is `IVideon Player`? It is not a part of ANdroid SDK. As well as `Utils.getDuration` and `Utils.getLong` - what are this 2 methods?

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko thnxx for reply. yes IVideon is sdk for media player. I am getting 0 for getCurrentPosition().  Utils.getDuration is method is converts long time to HH:mm:ss format

Comment: you likely using `getCurrentPosition` incorrectly

Comment: No its returning 0 while my media is playing

Comment: as I said, it is likely because you are using it incorrectly.

Comment: I tried and printed logs with this handler and thread but no lluck

Comment: I am getting problem because I am unable to get last position

Comment: ok, let me be more clear. As you didn't show how you use `getCurrentPosition`, I'm sure that you are using it incorrectly, and that's why you get it as 0 always. Nothing to say more before you show it.

Comment: Okay let me make clear. My requirement is that I am getting total duration from server. Now I need to update my seekbar for duration time. How can I make it working in case of start, stop and resume that  sir ?

Comment: mPlayer.load(clipUrl);
            mPlayer.setRotation(0);
            mPlayer.position();
            mBufferBar.setProgress(0);
            mBufferBar.setMax(event_list.getMqttRecordingItems().get(selectionPosition).getDuration()); //with the offset, you need to adapt the max value
            Log.d("Played Time", "startVideo: "+mPlayer.position()+ "Another :"+mPlayer.nativeMediaPlayer().getPosition());
            new Thread(new SeekBarProgress()).start();

Comment: And you didn't show how you are using `getCurrentPosition` again.

Comment: Actually, in this player, there is no any direct callback as getCurrentPosition. here is only  player.position

Comment: ok, show how you use it

Comment: I have no idea. I ma just searching in library but I am unable. Can you recommend me any solution ?

Comment: any example for any link would be appreciable for me

Comment: Now it is already totally unclear what you tried. First you say you did it, then you say that you honestly did not.  `I am getting 0 for getCurrentPosition().`, then you say that there is no `getCurrentPosition` in lib, but there is a `player.position`, then you say that you didn't try it regardless of you said that it didn't work for you. I'm tired trying to clear up what is true, and what is false in your story.

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko leave that.. I got it. Its beyond your limit. Its common sense  that getCurrentPosition return played time of a media but in this lib there is position() just like getCurrentPosition() in mediaPlayer. but this simple thing you can't understand. leave that.. You can not solve it.  anyways, Thank you